# Android Http connection

Tags: android, http

I try to connect to an url, one simple because after i want to connect to a server. For this i have

```
String urlServer = "http://www.google.com";
URL url = new URL(urlServer);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
```

The last line goes to the catch exception. I don't know what happens, I have also tried with this

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1", 8080));
conn = new URL(urlString).openConnection(proxy);
```

and it gives me

> true

The LogCat gives me

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Comment: "The last line goes to the catch exception" and the `Exception` says? Where's the logcat and what's the exception?

Comment: for the getOutputStream() you need a try{} catch{} so when the app try to do this it goes to the catch.

Comment: What do you get in Logcat when you write `e.printStackTrace();` in your `catch`?

Comment: sorry, it gives me android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/684582

Comment: @AlécioCarvalho a duplicate comment on a duplicate question? :P

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in asynctask...

```
public class Sample extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

just put your lines related to network in the doInBackground.